# Is there any binary relation operator that has these properties in any objects?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Consider binary relation operators

```
d b
q p
```

(with a direct correspondence by generalization of:

```
< >
≮ ≯
```

these are a subset of the above, thus they have mandatory rules as transitivity, which are not required is the generalized operators, whose FULL set of rules is described/directly deducible from the general statement below)

where $\forall x,\forall y,\ \  x\ \text d\ y \Leftrightarrow y\ \text b\ x\Leftrightarrow\lnot(x\ \text q\ y) \Leftrightarrow \lnot(y\ \text p\ x)$

There is a set of objects (which is the set of real numbers, for example, and real relation operators above whose generalization is made) such that transitivity applies; that is
$x\ \text d\ y \land y\ \text d\ z\Leftrightarrow x\ \text d\ z\Leftrightarrow\lnot(x\ \text q\ z)$. For the same example, a sort of "inantitransitivity" also applies, that is, $x\ \text d\ y \land y\ \text d\ z\Leftrightarrow x\ \text p\ z\Leftrightarrow\lnot(x\ \text b\ z)$. Note: check the correspondence between the general operators and the actual operators that apply to this example

Is there a set of objects such that intransitivity applies; that is
$x\ \text d\ y \land y\ \text d\ z\Leftrightarrow x\ \text q\ z\Leftrightarrow\lnot(x\ \text d\ z)$?

Is there a set of objects such that antitransitivity applies; that is
$x\ \text d\ y \land y\ \text d\ z\Leftrightarrow x\ \text b\ z\Leftrightarrow\lnot(x\ \text p\ z)$?

Thanks for reading. Please do comment if you see something that doesn't make sense (or some bad nomenclature, that's the thing that is wrong the most amount of times when one learns on the internet; I'm not sure those words exist).

Comment: [Wikipedia on posets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) may be of help here. Also some of your $\iff$ arrows are probably meant to be $\implies$.

Comment: @Mys, I read that article and although I didn't know about that, it doesn't answer my question. Those sets have incomparable elements; I'm asking for a set of fully-comparable elements with counter-intuitive properties. Thank you for the link anyway, it's always good to know. Also, I was thinking of using those one-way arrows, but I thought "in this case, if the first part leads to the second, the second leads to the first", that is, the converse is true, thus the two-headed arrow.

Comment: Now the question is updated, and doubts on it are cleared (check confusion below the answer of @PeterKošinár before posting a comment saying this is invalid), can anyone take a new look at this? BTW, does commenting bump a question to the front page?

Answer (score 0):

The use of equivalence instead of the more common implication in the definition of transitivity allows the following chain of reasoning: $a\operatorname{d} b \Rightarrow 
(\forall y)a\operatorname{d} y \Rightarrow (\forall y)(\forall x)x\operatorname{d} y$ (using the "back" arrow of the equivalence in both cases). In other words, if any two elements are comparable, all pairs compare... both ways; making the $d$-relation trivial. Did you really really want to use the equivalence?

In case you did, consider a small modification of the same argument applied to the "antitransitivity" case: $a\operatorname{d} b \Rightarrow (\forall x)b\operatorname{d} x\Rightarrow (\forall x)(\forall y)x\operatorname{d} y$ (again, the "back" arrow was used in both cases). Once again, any two elements being comparable imply all elements being comparable both ways (collapsing the relation to a trivial one).

Finally, the "intransitivity" turns out to be self-contradictory. Consider any element $a$ and the condition imposed by intransitivity for $(x,y,z)=(a,a,a)$: $(a\operatorname{d} a) \wedge (a \operatorname{d} a) \Leftrightarrow \neg(a \operatorname{d} a)$; a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, that's what I told @Myself, I want all pairs to be comparable, so that reasoning does apply.  I'm questioning the existence of a set where the referred non-tautological relations apply (transitivity, for instance, is not mandatory, and thus not tautological either). The relations you referred now are tautological according to my definition. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Be careful with the use of "comparable"; in the usual setting one wants to have $a\operatorname{d} b$ OR $b\operatorname{d} a$ whenever $a\not= b$ (i.e. every pair of distinct elements can be compared with "greater than" or "smaller than" outcome) but in your case the stronger definition implies that *both* of these are true at the same time... for all pairs. In general, equivalences of this form are pretty strong and tend to collapse the possible models to trivial ones.

Comment: How does it imply that $a\ \text d\ b \land b\ \text d\ a$? It simply doesn't imply it to be impossible (besides I don't say it to be impossible that $a = b$). I'm trying to put the less number of limitations possible, so than any set that has those characteristics can be accepted. That doesn't mean that set can't have other properties the generalization I defined doesn't.

Comment: No three equal elements can have the "intransitivity" property, as for no three equal elements does $a<a<a$ hold.

Comment: Ermm, you have the full proofs listed in the answer which show that both "transitivity-with-implication-replaced-by-equivalence" and your "antitransitivity" imply that $a\operatorname{d} b \Rightarrow (\forall x)(\forall y) x\operatorname{d} y$ which, as a special case, also implies $b\operatorname{d} a$. Thus, with any set of elements, if you want $d$ to be "transitive" (in your sense) or "antitransitive" you can either choose $d$ to be true for all pairs of elements it must be false for all pairs. No other relations of this kind exist. The intransitivity doesn't work on any non-empty set.

Comment: No, you got it all wrong. That wasn't what I meant! I didn't mean $\forall x,\forall y,\ \  x\ \text d\ y $, that is completely different from what I meant! I meant that for all two elements, $x$ and $y$ for which that relation holds, all the others hold, because those relations are equivalent; I mean, if one holds, the others do; and if one doesn't, the others don't. But if and only if one holds.

Comment: It's like when one says that $\forall p, \ p\rightarrow p$, one is NOT asserting $p$. Even if $p$ is false, the relation holds.

Comment: So, how are you interpreting the statement "$x \operatorname{d} y \wedge y \operatorname{d} z \Leftrightarrow \neg(x \operatorname{d} z)$"? I'm reading it as $(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z) x \operatorname{d} y \wedge y \operatorname{d} z \Leftrightarrow \neg(x \operatorname{d} z)$; there is no assertion that $(x\operatorname{d} y)$ would be true or anything such.

Comment: From what you said above and from your answer, you seemed to have made an assertion.